# Louvain/Leiden community clustering implementation in C/C++ for gene expression data

Tags: gene-expression, clustering

Does anybody know of a C/C++ based implementation of the Louvain or Leiden algorithms that will take gene expression looking csv input files, with the genes in columns and the samples in rows, and perform community clustering on it? Something like
@lh3lh3 https://github.com/lh3/bhtsne but for the community clustering algorithms.

Comment: igraph does Leiden and Louvain clustering. It is a C/C++ library and used in R or Python.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at the igraph library but couldn't find out how to turn the matrix of input data (e.g. the 28x28 pixel data from mnist) into an input graph to run the community clustering method.

Comment: I see. Personally I wouldn't use unsupervised learning for images (e.g. the MNIST data set), I'd use supervised learning: XGBoost is really cool for this BTW. Thus I dunno.